# CS1729 'MyNavigationPage' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments --> in visual studio 2019 community edition

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to add a navigation bar in Xamarin.forms

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new MyNavigationPage(new MyNavigationPage());
    }
```

I am getting this error -->  'MyNavigationPage' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument

I have tried adding a constructor but then the navigation bar does not appear.

Comment: don't you mean `new NavigationPage(new MyNavigationPage());`?

Comment: Yes........Thanku very much...... I am like doing it for 6 hours

Comment: If you solved this issue, please post you solution to answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was, we have to use the pre-build method "NavigationPage" instead of your own created page, in my case MyNavigationPage

new NavigationPage(new MyNavigationPage());